# how to convert a matrix into an image in opencv

Tags: c++, matlab, qt, opencv, matrix

i want to convert a matrix into an image as it said in the title the matrix is called B, so i could do some modification on it in the for loop
here is my code :

```
 Mat   image1 = imread("C://images//IntImage300915163313.bmp");
 //allocate new image
 int dim1[3] = {1000,1000,3};
 Mat B(3,dim1, CV_64F, Scalar::all(-1));
 for (int j1 = 0; j1 < 800; j1++)
 {
     for (int j2 = 0; j2 < 600; j2++)
     { 
     // compute indeces for corresponding pixels
         jj1 =  round( ((double)phi/stepphi)+700.0);
         jj2 =  round( ((double)theta/steptetha)+500.0);


         B.at<double>(1200-jj1,jj2,0) =  image1.at<double>(j1,j2);
         B.at<double>(1200-jj1,jj2,1) =  image1.at<double>(j1,j2);
         B.at<double>(1200-jj1,jj2,2) =  image1.at<double>(j1,j2);
     }
 }
```

for the moment the loop stops at j1 = 799 and j2 = 443 so i thought that there is a problem cause i affect image type to a matrix type

Comment: What do you mean by "the loop stops"? Does it crash?

Comment: I also don't get the "into an image" part. Do you mean `QImage` because of the tag that you have attached to your question? Or do you mean Matlab-compatible image because of another tag that points into this direction? Note that since OpenCV 3.0 there is an official Matlab API which however you can use only if you build OpenCV from source and enable the respective flags. Please clarify what you mean. Otherwise someone (perhaps even me) will remove the tags since currently your question doesn't have anything even remotely related to these.